# SQL Server 2014 - Cannot insert value into a primary key column, because of not existing "duplication"

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem, which at first glance looks pretty stupid(the error message seems descriptive enough), but actually is some kind of bug or corner case... I'm totally confused

I have the below SQL Insert code

```
USE Broker2
GO

DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Broker2.dbo.Properties');
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Broker2.dbo.Properties', RESEED, 9999);  
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Broker2.dbo.Properties ON

INSERT INTO Broker2.dbo.Properties
(Id, IsActive, Phone, Phone2, [Address], ExhibitionPoleId, RegionId, PropertyTypeId, FurnishingId, Price, IsDeposited, DepositAmount, IsArchived, 
CreatedOn, IsDeleted, OfficeId, DealTypeId, AssignedTo, HasTransition, BrokerNote)
SELECT 
    convert(int, '10000' + convert(varchar, cp.Id)), 
    cp.is_active, 
    (select SUBSTRING(op.phone, 0, 11) from recrm_merged.dbo.contact_phones op where op.id = ccp.id) as phone,
    (select SUBSTRING(op.phone, 12, 35) from recrm_merged.dbo.contact_phones op where op.id = ccp.id) as phone2, 
    cp.[address],
    me.broker_id, 
    mr.Broker_Id, 
    mp.Broker_Id, 
    mf.Broker_Id, 
    cp.price, 
    cp.with_deposit, 
    0, 
    case when cp.property_status_id = 1 then 0 else 1 end as IsArchived,
    cp.created_at,
    0,
    2,
    md.Broker_Id,
    cp.bound_to_broker_id,
    0,
    (cp.[description] + '; ' + cp.furniture_details)
FROM recrm_merged.dbo.properties cp
    join recrm_merged.dbo.contacts cc on cp.contact_id = cc.Id
    join recrm_merged.dbo.contact_phones ccp on cc.id = ccp.contact_id
    join Broker2.dbo.map_exhibition_types me on cp.exposure_id = me.crm_id
    join Broker2.dbo.map_regions mr on cp.district_id = mr.Crm_Id
    join Broker2.dbo.map_property_types mp on cp.property_type_id = mp.Crm_Id
    join Broker2.dbo.map_furnishings mf on cp.furnishing_id = mf.Crm_Id
    join Broker2.dbo.map_deal_types md on cp.action_type_id = md.Crm_Id

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Broker2.dbo.Properties OFF
```

I also have this table 'Properties', which according to the below result has no Ids bigger than 8469

```
select top 1000 * from Properties
order by id desc -- results in 8469, 8468, 8467 ...
```

And never the less I receive this error - "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Properties'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Properties'. The duplicate key value is (100003)."

The very first Id record from table recrm_merged.dbo.properties is 3. I need to have that newly transfered Ids to start with 10000

I restarted Management Studio, the PC and turn off and on the lights in my room, but the problem does not disappear...

It would be much appriciated if someone gives a shoulder!

EDIT

```
select * from recrm_merged.dbo.properties
where Id = 3 -- returns only 1 record.

USE [Broker2]
GO

/****** Object:  Index [PK_dbo.Properties]    Script Date: 18.9.2017 г. 21:46:00 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Properties] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Properties] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
```

EDIT 2

Actually I just spotted that my Select returns 3 records, which shoot me in the leg! How is this possible

```
Id  is_active   phone   phone2  address broker_id   Broker_Id   Broker_Id   Broker_Id   price   with_deposit    (No column name)    IsArchived  created_at  (No column name)    (No column name)    Broker_Id   bound_to_broker_id  (No column name)    (No column name)
100003  0   0889525467      басанович 9 4   221 11  1   260 0   0   1   2016-05-05 17:30:32 0   2   1   NULL    0   ; 
100003  0   123123      басанович 9 4   221 11  1   260 0   0   1   2016-05-05 17:30:32 0   2   1   NULL    0   ; 
100003  0   aaaa        басанович 9 4   221 11  1   260 0   0   1   2016-05-05 17:30:32 0   2   1   NULL    0   ;
```

Comment: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint means you are trying to insert duplicate value for primary keys in the table.. post the table schema information so be sure what is the primary key

Comment: Not a lot of details to work with here. But I suspect you have more than 1 row in your select statement with a value of 3. As such it will fail on the insert because it violates the primary key constraint.

Comment: Yea, as Sean said this is most likely an issue where the joins are doing a bit more joining than you expect duplicating your record with an id of 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your joins are cross multiplying and creating duplicates.  Either you have many-to-one relationships in one or more of the tables you're joining, or your join conditions are incomplete.

Try running this to find your duplicates:

```
SELECT cp.ID, COUNT(*)
FROM recrm_merged.dbo.properties cp
    join recrm_merged.dbo.contacts cc on cp.contact_id = cc.Id
    join recrm_merged.dbo.contact_phones ccp on cc.id = ccp.contact_id
    join Broker2.dbo.map_exhibition_types me on cp.exposure_id = me.crm_id
    join Broker2.dbo.map_regions mr on cp.district_id = mr.Crm_Id
    join Broker2.dbo.map_property_types mp on cp.property_type_id = mp.Crm_Id
    join Broker2.dbo.map_furnishings mf on cp.furnishing_id = mf.Crm_Id
    join Broker2.dbo.map_deal_types md on cp.action_type_id = md.Crm_Id
group by cp.ID
having count(*) > 1
```

From there you'll have to dig and find out which join is creating duplicates.

If you're certain all the records are going to be unique to `cp.ID`, you *may* be able to fix it with a `distinct`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    convert(int, '10000' + convert(varchar, cp.Id)), 
    cp.is_active, 
    (select SUBSTRING(op.phone, 0, 11) from recrm_merged.dbo.contact_phones op where op.id = ccp.id) as phone,
    (select SUBSTRING(op.phone, 12, 35) from recrm_merged.dbo.contact_phones op where op.id = ccp.id) as phone2, 
    cp.[address],
    me.broker_id, 
    mr.Broker_Id, 
    mp.Broker_Id, 
    mf.Broker_Id, 
    cp.price, 
    cp.with_deposit, 
    0, 
    case when cp.property_status_id = 1 then 0 else 1 end as IsArchived,
    cp.created_at,
    0,
    2,
    md.Broker_Id,
    cp.bound_to_broker_id,
    0,
    (cp.[description] + '; ' + cp.furniture_details)
FROM recrm_merged.dbo.properties cp
    join recrm_merged.dbo.contacts cc on cp.contact_id = cc.Id
    join recrm_merged.dbo.contact_phones ccp on cc.id = ccp.contact_id
    join Broker2.dbo.map_exhibition_types me on cp.exposure_id = me.crm_id
    join Broker2.dbo.map_regions mr on cp.district_id = mr.Crm_Id
    join Broker2.dbo.map_property_types mp on cp.property_type_id = mp.Crm_Id
    join Broker2.dbo.map_furnishings mf on cp.furnishing_id = mf.Crm_Id
    join Broker2.dbo.map_deal_types md on cp.action_type_id = md.Crm_Id
```

However, before using this method blindly you should stop and understand why you're getting duplicates.

Comment: Yeah... I excluded the joins on by one and found out that  'join recrm_merged.dbo.contact_phones ccp on cc.id = ccp.contact_id' brake my logic as returns for contact_id more than 1 record .....
The problem has been solved

Comment: just a small correction to the first count example - it should be '...having count(1) > 1', but not cp.Id > 1

Answer (score 0):

Do not try and set the key.  Change the "Id" column in the table under identity specification to "Is Identity = Yes".  This will handle the ID for you.  Then you just remove that from the insert and you're golden.  Then duplicate values returning from your one-to-many relationships won't crash you.